# Dynamic Reports - Display a hypelrink on every page to Top of the report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report, dynamic-reports

I am using the following piece of code to display a hyperlink on every page. On clicking this, I need to show the first page of the document.

```
.pageFooter(cmp.pageXofY().setFormatExpression("Page {0} of {1}"),cmp.text("Top").setStyle(plainstyle).setHyperLink(hyperLink().setTarget(HyperLinkTarget.TOP)));
```

What am I doing wrong here? I need this link to be displayed on every page. So, how do I do it without hard coding the page number? Also, it is not redirecting to the first page currently. What more changes need to be done?

Answer (score 0):

This is can be directly done in Jasper report design. No need of additional coding required. Apply the below properties to your text field which will display the hyperlink on every page except first page and clicking on it takes to the first page.

```
        <textField hyperlinkType="LocalPage">
            <reportElement x="130" y="20" width="124" height="19" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="3797dc6a-d310-433a-b538-d60ac9b81fd9">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} > 1]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Assignment2 value is "+$F{assignment2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            <hyperlinkPageExpression><![CDATA[Integer.valueOf(1)]]></hyperlinkPageExpression>
        </textField>
```

Hope this should solve your problem

Comment: And how should I do it if it has to be done through code?

Comment: What is the need for you to do it in code if it can be done through design itself?

Comment: We're using dynamic reports and the report is being generated from java code.